# Mongoose query not being evaluated

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am having trouble querying a MongoDB database using Mongoose.

I can't seem to figure out why the .find query is being skipped in the following script.

```js
'use strict';


// var apnagent = require('./notificationmodule/_header')

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var NotificationSchema = new Schema({
 userId: String,
 beachId: String,
 deviceId: String,
 message: String,
 notificationSent:{ type: Boolean, default: false},
 notificationSentDate: Date,
 notificationCreated: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
});

var Notifications = mongoose.model('Notification', NotificationSchema);

console.log("Script Started")

Notifications.find({}, function (err, result){ 
 console.log(result);
 console.log("This Callback never gets evaluated");
 });
 
console.log("Script Finished")
```

The Query itself doesn't seem to be evaluated as per the logs the "this...evaluated" statement never gets recorded. Upon researching Mongoose's documentation I found that query are apparently promisfyable now, but even adding a .then to the .find({}) request doesn't seem to evaluate the query. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong in this example and perhaps post up an example of what a query expression should look like?

Comment: Try with giving some criteria for find..

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. As it turns out this seems to not make a difference. Also an empty .find({}) should return all documents. I feel like I have done this before but posted the code to serif I was missing anything.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. I figured it out. I wrote this script outside of my server app.js script which connects to my db. Since I did not call mongoose.connect the query didn't Evaluate.